# what are the steps on how to create git branches from the terminal?

Tags: git

I am in a branch of my git project on the command line, I'd like to create a new branch that will duplicate the current branch that I am on.

what is the command to create a clone [or copy] of the current branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next time just look at github's documentation, its pretty self-explanatory but its just this command

```
git branch <new_branch_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new branch using 
`git checkout -b new_branch_name`

The new branch will have the exact same history and content as the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to create a branch based on your **dev** branch, located in your **origin** upstream.

1. `git fetch --all` this will pull all things to your local work copy, but it will not merge anything.
2. `git checkout -b my-new-branch origin/dev` this will create your new branch and immediately switch to that branch.

for a complete reference visit https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches